# typescript interface field to be const

Tags: typescript

there is my code

```
interface page {
  type: '1' | '2'
}

interface Menu {
  id: string,
  title: string,
  page: page,
}

export const menus: Menu[] = [
  {
    id: 'externalCustomer',
    title: 'title',
    page: { type: '1' }
  }
]
```

is there any way to make id be const?
the menus type is Menu[], and menu id is the const,
just like

```
interface page {
  type: '1' | '2'
}

interface Menu<T> {
  id: T[number].id,
  title: string,
  page: page,
}

export const menus: Menu<typeof menus>[] = [
  {
    id: 'externalCustomer',
    title: 'title',
    page: { type: '1' }
  }
]
```

i try to write it like

```
const menus = [
  {
    id: 'externalCustomer',
    title: 'title',
    page: { type: '1' }
  }
] as const
```

but in this way, the type of page will be lose

Comment: Making object immutable is what you asking you can use [Readonly type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#readonlytype).

Comment: even thoungh use  Readonly for id ,  (typeof menus[number])['id'] is still be string, is there any way to make id type be const ? like  'externalCustomer' | 'xxxx'

Answer (score 1):

Using union type might does the job.

```
interface page {
  type: '1' | '2'
}

interface Menu<I> {
  id: I,
  title: string,
  page: page,
}

const menus: Menu<'externalCustomer' | 'test'>[] = [
  {
    id: 'externalCustomer',
    title: 'title',
    page: { type: '1' }
  }, {
    id: 'test',
    title: 'title',
    page: { type: '1' }
  }, {
    id: 'aaa', //type error
    title: 'title',
    page: { type: '1' }
  },
];
```

Comment: the generic type of Menu is duplicated with the variable menu instance, can we use the the variable menu to  generate the <'externalCustomer' | 'test'>, just like '(typeof menus)[number].id', but I will get the error of 'Block-scoped variable 'menus' used before its declaration.'